# html escape characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, query-string

I have the following:

```
<form name="input" method="get" action="http://site:8083/Default.aspx?DC=" target="foo" onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=1100 height=500,status=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
<select name="DC">
<option value="1&Type=type1">1</option>
<option value="2&Type=type2">2</option>
<option value="3&Type=type3">3</option>
<option value="4&Type=type4">4</option>
<option value="5&Type=type5">5</option>
<option value="6&Type=type6">6</option>
<option value="7&Type=type7">7</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value=">>"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
```

Basically my querystring should be something like DC=1&Type=type1 the problem I have is that when I click the >> button above the html screws up the stirng by changing & to %26 and = to %3D

How can I make the value stay as I have it in the code above?

Comment: That is the correct behaviour. The characters have been URL encoded and this would work if you pasted it as a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the expected behaviour, the HTTP GET works this way, values are encoded to difference from keys. In GET, browsers append key=value pairs separated by '&' and starting with a '?'; you shouldn't specify them by yourself in the url.

I think you should change your code in this way, maybe it's what you want to get:

```
<form name="input" method="get" action="http://site:8083/Default.aspx" target="foo" onSubmit="updateType()">
<select name="DC">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <!-- etc... -->
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="Type"/>
<input type="submit" value=">>"/>
</form>
```

and in Javascript...:

```
function updateType(){
    // set up 'Type'
    document.forms[0].Type.value = 'Type' + document.forms[0].DC.value;
    // open popup
    window.open('', 'foo', 'width=1100 height=500,status=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')
    return true;
}
```

Comment: yes I just needed another select and now it gets created properly. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Forms are designed to submit key/value pairs of data where the key is the `name` of the control and the value is the `value`. They will not mash arbitrary strings together.

Design your server side program to expect input in the format the forms are designed to use.

Answer (score 0):

...and this is correct. Request-Parameters [get] should be encoded.
When you get the Request, your Server should decode them [apache/php] or i don't know ASP but in php it gaves a function called urldecode() ...

Comment: You don't need to decode them since he wants to use the values in a url and they are perfectly valid in a url. The issue is trying to do somthing that a form is not designed for.

Comment: I just needed to add another select and that fixes it, like so `<select name="Type"> <option value="type1">type1</option> <option value="type2">type2</option> </select>`

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do is have two different query string set to two different values when a single item on your form is set.  While your attempted solution is a neat idea, clearly the browser is actively preventing you from using that method (for security reasons) and rightly so.  I see two solutions that would work well for you.

1. Use the form to send just one query string (i.e. DC) and on the server side, determine what the value of 'Type' should be.  If it's really, really important to have both values as query strings (for example you're re-using a Control that only looks at those query strings) then use Server.Transfer on the server side to add the additional query string(s).
2. Provide two types of inputs on the form.  One being the select box that you have there, another being either a hidden select box, a hidden input field, or whatever else fits for you.  Add Javascript to the page such that when the selection is changed on the visible select box you set the hidden field to the correct value, then when the form is submitted both inputs are each submitting only one query string, as the browser is designed to support.

Here's an implemention of choice #2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var DCMapping = new Array();
DCMapping["1"] = "type1";
DCMapping["2"] = "type2";
DCMapping["3"] = "type3";
DCMapping["4"] = "type4";
DCMapping["5"] = "type5";
DCMapping["6"] = "type6";
DCMapping["7"] = "type7";
function selectionChanged(selectBox)
{
    alert(DCMapping[selectBox.value]);
    document.getElementById('hidType').value = DCMapping[selectBox.value];
}
</script>
<form name="input" method="get" action="http://site:8083/Default.aspx" target="foo" 
    onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=1100 height=500,status=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
    <select name="DC" onchange="selectionChanged(this)">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="Type" id="hidType" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value=">>"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`HttpUtility.UrlDecode();`

To convert escape characters in the url

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the method and action from the `<form>`. Instead extend the JavaScript/VBScript to pick up the value of the selected option and catenate it with the url root.

You don't need to mess with url decoding, the %.. should work fine as-is.